# compare single char in C

Tags: c, char

my code here

```
    char temp;
AGAIN:   
    printf("Enter char: "); scanf("%c", &temp);
    if (temp != 'A') goto AGAIN;
```

why did it go back to `AGAIN` even though my input is 'A' ?

If I put this block of code to `main()` function, it works correctly.

But if I do the same thing in the subrountine, it failed.

Comment: Did you enter a lowercase or uppercase 'A' in input?

Comment: @TimČas a tried it all, i dont know why a get stuck with this.

Comment: @PaulG - 60's? `goto` is commonly [used and advocated in the Linux community](http://kernel-janitor.sourceforge.net/kernel-janitor/docs/driver-howto.html)

Comment: @Mike I realize it's very low level and is probably essentially what the CPU does internally anyways, but it is considered by many to be bad practice and is known to lead to spaghetti code. Wasn't aware that it was still in use let alone advocated.

Comment: @PaulG It *is* what the CPU does. `goto` is essential in some places, like assembly code or high-performance/low-level C code. It just has a very narrow use-case that most developers don't venture into, so many see it as universally evil when it is just only the right tool for the job in a limited number of locations. Do we know if it's the right tool here? Not really.

Comment: @ajp15243: Don't forget `goto` for error handling. `if(error_cond) goto error; ... error: free_stuff(); return NULL;`

Comment: @TimČas Well, I didn't want to make an exhaustive list of `goto` uses, because I would still miss something I'm sure :).

Comment: @ajp15243: I know, but error handling is one of the more common (and IMHO appropriate) use cases of `goto`. That's why I wanted to specifically point it out.

Comment: @TimČas This is true, glad you pointed it out.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the `\n` character read by the `sacnf` is next call.
Try this

```
scanf(" %c", &temp);  
       ^ A space before %c can eat up any number of white-spaces
```

Comment: it've just tried it but it still didnt work :(

Comment: @GHD - Then you're probably doing something else you're not showing. Just wrapping your code in a `main()` function and using the space before the `%c` then this works

Comment: I use this in a subroutine. Just enter a char and check the condition, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

But for me, its work!. Are you given any other label as AGAIN in your program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
//./a.out
int main()
{
char temp;
calfunc(temp);
}
char calfunc(char temp)
{
    printf("Inside Function");
AGAIN:
printf("Enter char: "); scanf("%c", &temp);
if (temp != 'A')
    goto AGAIN;
else
    printf("Temp: %c\n",temp);
printf("Final: %c\n",temp);
return temp;
```

}

Result:

If type 'A', `Temp:A Final:A`
If type any other even 'a', `Enter char: Enter char:`. Then cursor places.

Comment: there's only 1 label named AGAIN, tried to use `while` loops too.
it still not work.

Comment: Sorry I have to make this clear.
If I put this block of code to `main()` function, it works correctly.
But if I do the same thing in the subrountine, it failed.
Can you explain to me why?

Comment: Sometimes fun makes grades. May you restart your Operating system and then compile it. Am also get interested what happened to you. However, `goto' is basic it gives headache both for you and me. Don't worry about dominating comments whenever comes from this website or wherever.

Comment: Ok. Now i'll edit the previous post which i do subroutine. And remember its also work!.